# JQuery append to selected item on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In short, I'm coming to have a series of divs on a page with this structure:

```
<div id="statuses">
   <p><?php echo $status; ?></p>
   <div id="statuscom">
      <a id="comment" href="#">Comment</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

And when the comment href is clicked I want it to append another div to the div which has been clicked, and only that div.

I have this:

```
$(function {
    $("a#comment").click(function() {  
        $(this).append("<div id=\"statuscomadd\"</div>");
    });
});
```

Which doesn't seem to do anything, again, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check your markup in .append()

Comment: This is bad! If you click on the div more than once, you will add multiple divs with the same id. Id's must be unique!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your syntax is wrong (the function has no parameters, nor a simple `()`)
2. Your HTML is wrong (`div` not closed)
3. If you wanto to create a click handler on page load, use `$(document).ready(...)` or `$(function () {...})`
4. You are appending an empty DIV next to A tag, it's that what you want?
5. Why using an id (`statuscomadd`) when you can click and add more than one div, as another user said? Better use a class. Or, if you have to add only one div, use the `.one()` handler.

Try:

```
$(function () {
    $("a#comment").click(function() {  
        $(this).append("<div class=\"statuscomadd\"></div>");
    });
});
```

Comment: 1) I figured it might be, kinda new to JQuery.
2) My bad, sorry.
3) Thanks for the tip
4) Yeah, I've yet to fill it, but it has pre-set height and width so it still displays.
5) Thanks, I'll change to .one() 
6) Works great, much appreciated.

Comment: @AviateX14 No, it's a plain Javascript error. A function (closure in this case) must always have parameters, or "()" if zero parameters expected.

Comment: @AviateX14 Glad you've sorted it out :)

Comment: Okay, not entirely, sorry, each of the divs does have a unique ID and what not, but how would I pass that to JS and stop it from generating multiple divs if clicked repeatedly?

Comment: @AviateX14 use `.one` instead of `.click` here: `$("a#comment").click(function() { `   http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't have multiple tags on the same page with the same ID (comment).

Having said that, there are a few issues with your code: missing parentheses at `function`, appending to the `<a>` tag and syntax issues in HTML.  Overall, it should be something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("a#comment").click(function() {  
        $("<div id=\"statuscomadd\"></div>").insertAfter(this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not append the div to  tag. Instead, you should append it after that tag (or before, maybe)

```
$(function() {
    $("a#comment").click(function() {  
        $('<div id="statuscomadd"></div>').insertAfter(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: I understand the problem in case of more than one <a>  with same id, but why .one() ?

Comment: I think it's a commenting system (but it's an assumption), so it may be that the A id is unique. I suggested "one" in case the user wants to add only one div. Without deeper explanations it's difficult to understand...

Comment: It's probably supposed to be `$(document).ready(` rather than `$(`

Answer (score 0):

syntax is wrong div is not closed

```
$(function {
    $("a#comment").click(function() {  
    $(this).append("<div id=\"statuscomadd\"></div>");
   });
 });
```